# new .net floating point types for x64?

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit

Does anybody know if there are any? I would be interested in a .net floating point type with the range of a double (or greater) combined with the precision of a decimal (or greater). Are there any planned? Anybody interested in speculating as to the usefulness or practicality of a new high-precision, high-range floating point type on x64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x64 still has the same core .NET libraries as x86 (although there may be some internal changes, especially in the CLI itself). So no: x64 doesn't get anything extra.

There is [`BigInteger`](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/11/04/what-s-new-in-the-bcl-in-net-4-0-justin-van-patten.aspx) in 4.0, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's your opinion though: do you think that a new high-precision, high-range floating point type would be both feasible and useful for those working on the x64 platform on .net?

Comment: @Shunyata: x86 floating point supports wider types that .NET (or VC++) exposes as it is. More likely (hopefully in .NET 4) is some BigFloat for arbitrary precision.

Comment: IMO, that is quite a specialized requirement... it would be *nice* if they were there, but we've done OK without them so far. I expect you can pick up some arbitrary precision libraries online.

Comment: @Richard: Thanks for the info. I would welcome some sort of BigFloat in x86, I just thought that in x64 the performance overhead would be lower for such a beast.

Comment: To have better performance, it would need to use new CLI primitives in the implementation... AFAIK, that isn't happening.

Comment: @Marc: Ok, I see, and thanks for the info. Am I correct in thinking, then, that such a BigFloat type could perform better on x64 than x86 given the necessary CLI changes?

Comment: That isn't a simple question... it would depend entirely on the unmanaged part of the system (not my specialist subject). I guess potentially it *could*, **if** there are CPU instructions to handle that data natively.